# Value of $H$ at the emission of the CMB

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, cosmic-microwave-background

According to the lambda CDM model, $H_0$ is around 67.7. If this value was calculated from a value for $H$ at the emission of the CMB, what was it, or do we have constraints on its value at that time?

Comment: The question is also about how the present value of 67.7 is arrived at - I assumed it was calculated from a value for H at the CMB time, but that might be wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Related: ["How does the Hubble parameter change with the age of the universe?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136056/145491); ["Value of the Hubble parameter over time"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18301/145491).

Comment: The question includes how the value of 67.7 was arrived at, whether from the CMB emission value or not. Thanks for those links, but they don't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

No, the current CMB based value for $H_0$ is not directly calculated from the value for $H_\mathrm{ls}$ at the time of last scattering when the CMB was emitted. As discussed in the answer to ["How is Hubble's constant (the expansion rate) predicted from LCDM and the CMB?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/751762/145491), the value depends on comparing the currently observed angular distribution of CMB intensity fluctuations to [Lambda-CDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model) model predictions for ther physical size of these fluctuations at the [time of last scattering](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Glossary/Essay_lss.html). The longer the time (which depends on $H_0$), the bigger the angles.

As discussed in the answers to

- ["How does the Hubble parameter change with the age of the universe?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136056/145491),
- ["Value of the Hubble parameter over time"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18301/145491), and
- ["Equation for Hubble Value as a function of time"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92484/145491),

$H$ does change with time. The [value at the time of last scattering](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2211.04492) can be calculated in the standard cosmological model to be:

$$H_\mathrm{ls} = 100\,\mathrm{km/sec/Mpc}\;\omega_r^{1/2}(1+z_\mathrm{ls})^2\sqrt{1+\frac{\omega_m}{\omega_r}\frac{1}{1+z_\mathrm{ls}}}\sim 2.3\times 10^4 H_0$$

where

- $\omega_r$ is the total physical radiation density,
  $$\omega_r=\left[1+\frac{7}{8} N_\mathrm{eff} \left(\frac{4}{11}\right)^{4/3}\right]\omega_\gamma$$
- $\omega_\gamma= 2.47\times 10^{−5}$ is the physical photon energy density,
- $N_\mathrm{eff}=3.06$ is the [effective number of light neutrinos](https://indico.cern.ch/event/336103/contributions/786522/attachments/1204254/1754196/TEXAS-Neff-Slides.pdf),
- $\omega_m=0.142$ is the physical nonrelativistic-matter density, and
- $z_\mathrm{ls}\approx 1080$ is the redshift corresponding to the time of last scattering.

For estimated constraints on $H_\mathrm{ls}$, I leave it as an exercise to look up the uncertainties in all the imput values and estimate the total uncertainty. (Model uncertainties and possible correlations between the input values may be an issue.)

Answer (score 0):

The CMB was emitted when

$\rm a=1/(z+1)=1/1090$,

so with

$\rm H(a)=H_0 \ \sqrt{\Omega_R/a^4+\Omega_M/a^3+\Omega_{\Lambda}}$

and

$\rm \Omega_R=9.2136e-5, \ \Omega_M=0.315, \ \Omega_{\Lambda}=1-\Omega_R-\Omega_M$

we get

$\rm H(a)=23194 \cdot H_0$